# Had to replace brakes and rotors in the front on a 1 year old vehicle - this normal?

Tags: toyota, brakes, brake-rotor, tacoma

I added some pictures of the rotors that they said had developed bad grooves because of rust. Is this normal? This is from a 2021 Toyota Tacoma.

I'm at 35000km, which is a lot after 1 year, but I still think replacing the front 2 rotors already seems ridiculous. Thoughts?

[image]

[image]

Comment: It is kinda hard to tell the depth of the groove. To me it looks as though the vehicle sat for a good length of time, then was driven, which knocked down the rust pitting. Don't really know though.

Comment: Odd, the most it has ever sat was 3 weeks when I was on vacation. But I've done that with lots of other vehicles and this never happened (new ones).

Comment: The rotors you have shown are both the front rotors? Is there any way to provide what the friction side of the brake pads look like in comparison to where they ride on the rotor?

Comment: Yes both front. I wish I would have taken pictures of the pads, but I didn't.

Comment: I had an f150 before that which I drove from new for over 3 years and never had rotor issues like this. I'm struggling to understand how the Tacoma is different.

Comment: I'm wondering if this might have been a flood vehicle before you purchased it?

Comment: The biggest issue I'm seeing from the issues is the wear pattern of the pads on the rotors is different between the two rotors. The wear patterns are not equal. Makes me wonder if there was an issue from the factory. They should be equal so the wear areas are the same and equal amounts of frictional stopping force is getting applied to each side. Without this, it will dig deeper grooves on the "short" side versus the side which has full coverage.

Comment: I purchased it brand new

Comment: So if this was an issue from the factory, would the installation of the new rotors fix this entirely now, or could it be a problem with the caliper?

Comment: I would "think" it should fix the issue. You can definitely tell the wear bars are different between the two, but who knows what the reason was for that difference. It could be the factory installed the wrong pad(s) onto the vehicle. Stupid things happens and the factory is not a perfect place, mainly because there are humans behind the machines. If you had someone do the replacement work, you should ask them what they saw.

Comment: It was someone at the Toyota dealership that did it. They just tried blaming it on rust buildup, but it doesn't make sense.

Comment: The friction mark on the back of the rotor is thinner than the front. That has to heat unevenly. Why would the pattern on the back be so thin? Is the back wear pattern the same for both rotors?

Comment: Are you sure they were off your car?

Comment: Looks like the calipers were ground all the way down. Either you have a very challenging driving environment, or you drive super harsh (e.g. hammering pedals all the time, or dragging brakes going down a hill everyday because you don't know how to engine brake).  It never hurts to stop and validate that your driving habits are reasonable.   Remember everytime you press the brakes you are wasting kinetic energy *that you spent gasoline to buy*.  So manage your kinetic energy skillfully so you are both powering and braking less.  That light won't turn green any faster by racing up to it. Etc.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on use ; I have 90,000 miles and pads look excellent; An acquaintance does amature road racing and needs pads after a race weekend.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the calipers were ground all the way down. That's pretty weird for 2 years and 20,000 miles.

### Why

Well, one possibility is you have an inherently challenging driving environment, e.g. you drive around Manhattan all day.  Even a sensible driver would use brakes that fast there.

The other possibility is that you drive roughly,  either due to lack of skill, or strong expression of personality via driving style.

Once I was tailgated for a moment by a Mustang. The guy was trying to go 90 mph but couldn't due to medium-heavy traffic. The Mustang would race up to people, tailgate, snap across lanes, get boxed in - all emotions no strategy.  I **kept up with the Mad Mustang *for ten miles*** without tailgating or cutting anyone off (and obviously not hard accelerating since **I had a Geo Metro**).   It was unbelievable **just how unproductive** the drivers' "Mash the gas mash the brake" bad attitude was.  I was doing the same thing with no brake wear since I was thinking ahead. That's not incompetence, it's testosterone poisoning, driver was all attitude.

### How to beat it

An important secret: brakes destroy **kinetic energy**.  Kinetic energy is the square of speed.  50 mph has four times the kinetic energy of 25 mph. 75 mph has 9 times.  You buy kinetic energy by buying gasoline.  You throw away kinetic energy by using brakes.

Capische? When you press the brake pedal you are destroying kinetic energy **you paid for**. So, now let your thrifty gene kick in.  *Do I need to apply this power (gas)? What if I don't?*

For example, a traffic light is 1600' (500m) away.  If you have a high level of situational awareness, you know about the light and know it is "stale green", you're not going to make it and are likely to need to stop. Thus, you can get off the gas right there and coast up to the light. When you do brake, you are braking from 30 mph (50 kph) instead of 60 mph (100 kph), meaning 75% less brake pad wear. You also save the gas not burned.  You may also get lucky and have the light turn while you are still coasting down, then you use your judgment as to when to speed back up so starting-up traffic is not in your way.  It's often possible to not brake at all.

Of course many people only focus their attention 300' (~100m) ahead or so, and so they cruise most of that 1600' (500m) with foot on the gas, only braking to avoid hitting stopped traffic ahead. This is hard on the brakes.

"Hypermiling" is the name of techniques designed to save gasoline.  The single best way to save gasoline is not invest in *kinetic energy* and then immediately burn it up in the brakes.  Thus, many "hypermiling" techniques are also excellent for reducing brake wear.